# ImageCaptureConfig.Builder() is showing error

Tags: android, android-camera, androidx

I am trying to implment camera option using androidX.camera2. I am following 
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/take-photo.

I have added this libraries :

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-alpha08"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:${camerax_version}"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha05"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

On bindPreview function i have add code for image capture.

```
        ImageCaptureConfig config = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                        .build();
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture(config);
```

but builder function is showing error. [image]

How can i solve this error?

Comment: show to us your imports top of this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 1.0.0-alpha07 configuration is different:

```
ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                        .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                        .build();

Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
```

You should see [changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera-core-1.0.0-alpha07) for details.

Comment: sorry mate for late reply.  Actually android have just released the alpha9 version and the issue is solved using that version and your code also helped.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the `camerax_version` to `1.0.0-alpha06` and removing the following dependencies seems to fix the issue:

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha05"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha05"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-alpha02"
```

This is as per the `build.gradle` in their sample app: [camera-samples/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/build.gradle)
I'm guessing this will be fixed soon enough since it is still in `alpha`

Comment: sorry mate for late reply.  Actually android have just released the alpha9 version and the issue is solved using that version.